# FL Studio strange wobbly sound

Tags: fl-studio

I have a pretty annoying issue with FL Studio.
Basically, sometimes happens that certain notes I play start to sound strange and wobbly, and it doesn't seem to be related to a single VST. It sounds like this: http://vocaroo.com/i/s0agtQPNIOYV.

I tried fiddling with every setting of FL Studio possible, but it doesn't seem to be an issue related to buffers and stuff like that.
The strange thing is that a new project doesn't present this issue, and it happens, it seems, randomly.

I tried reinstalling FL Studio, but to my surprise the issue stayed in the same project I had the issue before.
I think it may be some setting I accidentaly change midway, but I cannot find what triggers it.

Comment: If a wobble is your problem in fruity loops, perhaps you should turn off "dubstep" mode.(That's a joke) :)

Comment: Can you re-upload the sample please?

Comment: There's already this question with some answers already on the site...

Comment: see if pitcher is on the master track tht was the problem fr me and if it is turn off pitcher

Answer (score 1):

Try turning off all effect switches on the bottom of your mixer, also make sure the "selected"mixer channel is empty.

If the problem still occurs, solo a VST and recheck for strange noises, if not found, try tools > macros > switch auto disable for all plug-ins.

If it's still not fixed, check the sample quality, is it still 44000?

Or, reconnect your MIDI keyboard (if you're using one) and rescan devices.

Answer (score 1):

Typically, ModWheels are assigned to automatically create a vibrato in the instrument. Unfortunately, I'm unable to listen to the piece of audio you've provided in the OP as for I get a "file does not exist" message but make sure your modulation values on your tracks are set to '0'.

Answer (score 0):

Is it a registered version or are you using the demo version? I remember back in the day when I couldn't get my hands on a legit copy that the instruments would wobble and screech because the version I had was only a demo. It's like a way to get you to buy it. If that's not the issue get back to me and we'll figure this out.